# Two separate columns of buttons

Tags: css, button

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to space out 6 buttons. I want is so that three of the buttons are at the top, while the other 3 are below the top row.  So basically it would be two separate rows of aligned buttons.

I know this seems fairly easy but I'm having a difficult time with it. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do something as such:

```
<div id="button-wrapper">
    <div class="button-row">
        <input type="button" value="button1" />
        <input type="button" value="button2" />
        <input type="button" value="button3" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-row">
        <input type="button" value="button4" />
        <input type="button" value="button5" />
        <input type="button" value="button6" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
#top
{
width: 100%
}

#bottom
{
width: 100%;
}
.button
{
float: left
width: 33%;
}

<div id="top"> 

 <div class="button">
  <!-- code for button here -->
 </div>

 <div class="button">
  <!-- code for button here -->
 </div>

 <div class="button">
  <!-- code for button here -->
 </div>
</div>



<div id="bottom">
 <div class="button">
    <!-- code for button here -->
 </div>
 <div class="button">
    <!-- code for button here -->
 </div>
 <div class="button">
  <!-- code for button here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

You can play with the button div width and add margins/padding ect.

Comment: Is there a way to do with without the hmtl tag?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure column alignment, you could add a column class to each, and specify a width in that column class.

HTML:

```
<div id="button-wrapper">
    <div class="button-row">
        <input type="button" value="blah blah" class="c0"/>
        <input type="button" value="lorem ipsum" class="c1"/>
        <input type="button" value="really long button label" class="c2"/>
    </div>
    <div class="button-row">
        <input type="button" value="button4" class="c0"/>
        <input type="button" value="button5" class="c1"/>
        <input type="button" value="button6" class="c2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.c0{
    width: 80px;
}
.c1{
    width: 100px;
}
.c2{
    width: 150px;
}
```